# Understanding central difference formula for computing numerical gradient

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

[image]

More can be found here: http://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math3600/lecture27.pdf.

I'm having trouble understanding what happens to the $h$ in this example where the central difference error is derived. It's not in the typical form that I'm used to seeing. For example: What happens to the $h$ in $f(x_{i})$ and how do we go from $(x-a)^{2}/{2}$ to $h^{2}/2$?

Comment: We simply set $h=(x-x_0)$ to get a sense of the "size" of the neighborhood we're working with ($h$ is like an indicator of precision). Hence the usual $f(x)=\sum_{n \ge 0} \dfrac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ becomes $$f(x_0+h)=\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!}h^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Two items:

$x-a = h$,
because $h$
is the difference between
$x$ and $a$.

When the two formulas
are subtracted,
the $f(x_i)$
and $f''(x_i)$
terms cancel out,
and we get
(writing $x$ instead of $x_i$)

$\begin{array}\\
f(x+h)-f(x-h)
&=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+h^3f'''(c_1)/6)\\
&-(f(x)-hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2-h^3f'''(c_1)/6)\\
&=2hf'(x)+h^3(f'''(c_1)+f'''(c_2))/6\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)-h^3(f'''(c_1)+f'''(c_2))/6}{2h}\\
&=\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
-\dfrac{h^3(f'''(c_1)+f'''(c_2))/6}{2h}\\
&=\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
-\dfrac{h^2(f'''(c_1)+f'''(c_2))}{12}\\
\end{array}
$